# $(p \implies q) \wedge (p \implies r) = p \implies (q \wedge r)$ PROOF

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

$\def\implies{\to}$I am trying to prove the following: $$(p \implies q)\wedge (p\implies r) \equiv (p\implies q \wedge r) $$

I did this, although I am second-guessing because of the parenthesis placement and the order of operations:

$$ \begin{align}(p \implies q) \wedge (p \implies r) &\equiv (\neg p \vee q)\wedge (\neg p \vee r) \\[1ex] &\equiv \neg p \vee (q \wedge r) \\[1ex] &\equiv p \implies (q\wedge r)\end{align}$$

Any help/insight on this is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange, Rach.  Your work looks good.  You used the distributive property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your work looks good.

You used that $a\implies b$ is equivalent to $\lnot a \lor b$.

You also used the distributive property of disjunction over conjunction:

$(a \lor b) \land (a \lor c)$ is equivalent to $a \lor (b \land c)$.

(There is also a distributive property of conjunction over disjunction, but you didn't need that.)

Comment: Thank you! :) makes sense

Comment: You're welcome.  Hope to hear some more challenging problems from you in the future